# $(...).live is not a function error and checkbox checked error

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, click, jquery

I'm trying to update some database rows from the information used on a form, but it's got a few errors

Here's the code in question:

```
  var html = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".save_btn").on('click', function() {

        $('.response').each(function(){
            //alert($(this).attr('id'));

            var $no = no.checked;
            var $yes = yes.checked;

            alert($no);
            alert($yes);

            if ($no === 'no') {
                html = $.ajax({
                    url: "response14.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&question=" + $(this).val() + "&check=2",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
            }   
            if ($yes === 'yes') {
                html = $.ajax({
                    //url: "response.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&response=" + $(this).val() + "&check=1",
                    url: "response14.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&question=" + escape($(this).val()) + "&check=1",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
            }   

        }); 
        alert(html);
        location.reload();  
    });
})
```

response14.php:

```
include("db_conn.php");
$sql = "update questions set approved = 1, question = ? where questionID = ?";
$qc = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$qc->execute(array($_GET['question'], $_POST['questionID']));
echo 'saved';
```

the code with the button:

```
echo "<script src='viewsonly.js' type='text/javascript'> </script><br><center>";    
    include("db_conn.php");

$qry_strings4 = "SELECT * FROM `Y new questions`";
$preps4 = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_strings4);
            $preps4->execute();
           // $row = $preps4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //echo "$count";
            echo "<table style='border:0px; background-color:lightgrey; width:75%'><thead style='border:0px;'><tr style='border:0px solid white; background-color:#153E7E; text-align:left; color:white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Question</th><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Response</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            while ($row = $preps4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<tr style='border:1px white; background-color:lightgrey; color:black; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><td style='border:1px white; vertical-align:top; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>{$row['starName']}</td>
                      <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><div id='wrap'>
<textarea cols='85' rows='2' id='{$row['questionID']}' class='response textbox'>{$row['question']}</textarea>
    YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='yes'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no' value='no'>    </div></td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";
            echo "<button type='button' class='save_btn' style='align:right'>Save All</button><br>";
```

rendered html:

```
   <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><div id='wrap'>
<textarea cols='85' rows='2' id='3792' class='response textbox'>Hello C!!

Where can I send you fan mail? :)
I want your autograph and I'm from the Philippines :)

God bless Cooper!</textarea>
    YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='yes'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no' value='no'>    </div></td></tr><tr style='border:1px white; background-color:lightgrey; color:black; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><td style='border:1px white; vertical-align:top; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Gavin Casalegno</td>
                      <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><div id='wrap'>
<textarea cols='85' rows='2' id='3793' class='response textbox'>What is your religion?
Do you believe in God?
How much you measure height?</textarea>
    YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='yes'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no' value='no'>    </div></td></tr></tbody></table><button type='button' class='save_btn' style='align:right'>Save All</button><br>
```

And here's the error message:

> TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
>
> $(".save_btn").live('click', function() {

Any ideas on why?

Comment: Why use ajax when you reload the page? Also what is no and yes? $(no) would not work in my opinion unless you have `var no = "#someRadioWithIdNo"`

Comment: thank you, that was my next question haha "ReferenceError: no is not defined $no = no.checked;" it's a checkbox, would that still work? var no = "no.checked;" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. .live is deprecated use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
2. where are no and yes defined? If `<input type="radio" id="no" />` then you need `$("#no")` but then you test for value and that does not make sense.
3. Show some HTML - you seem to have more than one response and each of them has yes/no? if so they need to be named to be found. ID must be unique

You do not even need Ajax:

```
$(function(){
  $(".save_btn").on('click', function() {
    var check = $("input[name=no]").is(":checked")?2:1;
    // $(this).attr("id") next is the ID of the save button
    location = "response14.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') +
       "&question=" + $(this).val() + "&check="+check;
  });          
});
```

Seriously use

```
YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes[]' value='yes'>
NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no[]' value='no'>
```

and just submit the whole form!!!

If you want ajax (and I see from your comment you might need it since you want to post) try this

```
$(function(){
  $(".save_btn").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // in case you have a submit button
    var check = $("input[name=no]").is(":checked")?2:1;
    $.post("response14.php",{
        "questionID":$(this).attr('id'),
        "question":$(this).val(),
        "check":check
      },function(response) { 
      $("#someOutputDiv").html(response);
    });
  });          
});
```

Comment: oh ok, wt's the 2:1 about? also why .live and not .on ?

Comment: I forgot to remove the live. The 2/1 is a ternary it is the same as `if (no is checked) check=2; else check=1`

Comment: ahh i see, added that now, ahh interesting to know

Comment: I strongly suggest you rethink your approach. You cannot loop the way you do, it would (when working as you expected) only ever alert the last response. Instead submit the complete form and use the [] array notation in the name of the radio. Then you get no=["no",,,,"no"] and yes=[,"yes","yes","yes",,"yes"]

Comment: so close, `response14.php?questionID=undefined&question=&check1` questionID and question, also check1 should be check = 1 shouldn't be blank though and better if they get POST instead of GET i think aswell, also it said echoed saved but didn't update the database though

Answer (score 4):

```
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

$(".save_btn").live('click', function() {
```

above error is because `.live()` is deprecated from newer version of `jQuery` use `.on()`

```
$(".save_btn").on('click', function() {
 -------------^^^----
```